# Mysqli SELECT INSERT and UPDATE Query simulatenously

Tags: php, database, mysqli, insert

Hello I have a Database named as "admin" in which i have two tables 
Table 1 Name = "register"
Table 2 Name = "noti"

In Register Table i've approx more than 10+ User entries which comes through Registration Page 
In Noti Table, its empty at this time (Column Name is also "noti")

I want to perform this thing
First I want to count the total no. of records in "register" table 
and it checks, if the records are greater than ZERO then it runs the INSERT query otherwise it runs the UPDATE Query

And i want to INSERT and UPDATE that count value into "noti" table

Here's my code

```
<?php 
include('config.php');
$sql2 = "SELECT count(*) as count FROM register";
$result2 = mysqli_query($con, $sql2);
if($result2->num_rows>0)
{
while($rw1=$result2->fetch_array())
{
$value1 =  $rw1['count'];

$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT count(*) as count FROM register  ");

if(!empty($value1)) {
    mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE noti SET noti = '$value1' ");
}
else
{
    mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO noti(noti) VALUES ('$value1') ");
}
}
}
?>
```

Comment: if(!empty($value1)) changed this to if($value1==0).. i told u do the same thing previuosly

Comment: plus echo your $value1 to see the result

Comment: I already tried this code buddy yesterday, but it not works , that's why i reposted again...

Comment: did you echo the result of $value1 ??

Comment: Firstly remove `$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT count(*) as count FROM register  ");` Try **$value1 > 0** within if condition

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
include('config.php');
$sql2 = "SELECT count(*) as count FROM register";
$result2 = mysqli_query($con, $sql2);
$count = $result->num_rows;
if($count != 0)
{
    mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE noti SET noti = '$count' ");
}
else
{
    mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO noti(noti) VALUES ('$value1') ");
}
```